# Trying to run mantel test on asymetric distance matrices.. ideas?

Tags: r, vegan

I am trying to compare distances matrices belonging to two species matrices. One is bacteria and the other is ectomycorrhizal fungi. Both species matrices were generated from the same plant roots using different extraction methods.

I want to compare the species composition between the two matrices to determine if the bacterial and ectomycorrhizal compositions are correlated in different plant roots. The problem I am facing is that the bacterial matrix is much larger than the ectoymycorrhizal matrix and thus they are asymetric.

I know that Mantel's test does not require symmetric matrices in theory, however the packages I have found that run mantel tests all *do* require symmetrical matrices. I have tried vegan, ade4 and ape and all have given issues when trying to run the mantel test.

Does anybody have any ideas as to how I can modify my data to run in one of these packages, or perhaps another package that can run a mantel test on asymmetric data?

Thanks!